# Music Score WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript

I'm intending to make a javascript WYSIWYG to edit Music Score. Does anybody know any relevant javascript library or something like that? Also I'm so curious to know whether there is any similar open source project out there.

So I thought stackoverflow would be the best place to ask.

Ideas are all welcome on implementation.

Comment: Totally off topic, but [Lilypond](http://lilypond.org/) is great.

Comment: "Gee I'd like to write some music. I'd prefer a nice graphical interactive editor, but if necessary I'll write a JavaScript program to write the music for me."  Kind-of weird.

Comment: about six months ago (maybe more?), there was a post on Slashdot where they linked to a tech demo of a musical score done with HTML5 Canvas. It certainly wasn't editable or interactive, but it was the first time I'd personally seen anything done using canvas. These days canvas is everywhere, but I haven't seen anything since then that does music.

Comment: okay, google remembered it - this was the demo I saw on Slashdot: http://0xfe.blogspot.com/2010/05/music-notation-with-html5-canvas.html

Comment: This link is really cool. I had a look just now and find another cool stuff which calls [abcjs](http://drawthedots.com/abcjs). I believe this would be helpful as well. Thanks.

Comment: All I need to do find a way to make them or probably one them interactive.

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed - it is a programming question: the OP wants to find a Javascript library that will help him write a music site. If someone had asked the same question about HTML JS editors, he would have had loads of answers (or more likely referred to a previous question), so why did one about a music editor get closed? Voting to re-open (not that it'll make much difference though).

Comment: @Spudley, thanks for your support. I can't understand why my question is off topic. But anyway you guys are really helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: @nmichaels: Can I ask why do you (or others who close this question) think that this question is not about programming or software? Is it about playing the Guitar???

Comment: The way I read it, it's about software for editing musical scores. I don't see what that has to do with programming. The javascript library phrase looks like a non sequitur. If what you actually want is not a wysiwyg editor, but a package that will let you build or embed one in your program, say so (and which) in the question and I'll vote to reopen it.

Comment: @nmichaels: You're right actually. I should have mention it in more like technical way. Thanks for your new vote and BTW Lilypond is really awesome project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest thing I know of in Javascript is this: http://0xfe.blogspot.com/2010/05/music-notation-with-html5-canvas.html

It's not WYSIWYG editable, so probably won't suit you, but it seems to be about as good as it gets in Javascript/HTML5 right now.

Hopefully things will improve in the future, but I don't think what you're looking for is available yet.

Comment: vexflow looks good looking site too

Comment: @Omid: Glad that helped. Yep, vexflow seems to be the site he set up for it (I only went as far as the blog). abcjs looks promising too. Hope you manage to achieve what you're wanting to do.

Comment: That was all your help BTW. Thank you very much again! I'm actually willing to write something like a WYSIWYG so this would be really helpful. Also I am intending to make it open source so lets see :) .

Answer (score 1):

I think https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/ will be useful for your project.